# How to enforce a List containing mixed types?

Tags: java, list, generics, java-8

I have a Java class which will represent an array of data to be sent to a third-party:

```
import java.util.List;

abstract class DataToSend<T> {
    private T value;
    public T getValue() { return value; }
}
public class ListToSend extends DataToSend<List> {
   // ...
}
```

I am not able to change `DataToSend`, and `ListToSend` must extend `DataToSend`.

The third-party allows this list to contain ints, floats, booleans or Strings, and allows these types to be mixed. How can I enforce this?

For example, I could use a raw `List` or `List<Object>`, but then that would allow e.g. Maps to be put inside the list - I don't want this.

I could also define a 'ListElement' class like this:

```
class ListElement {
    private int a;
    private float b;
    private boolean c;
    private String d;
}
```

And say that `ListToSend extends DataToSend<List<ListElement>`.

**Is there a better option?**

Comment: `ListToSend` shouldn't redefine `value` and `getValue()`.

Comment: @Kayaman Ah yes, thank you.

Comment: Depending on what you want, you could have your `ListElement` hold an `Object`, and have constructors for the specific types. Having 4 variables of which 3 are always unused would be complex to handle.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably many solutions to this but we have limited knowledge on the flexibility you have.

For sure you can't use primitives in the proposed `ListElement` - how would you know which one was set if by default all will have default values (int: 0, boolean: false, String: null)?

For example - how do you create and manage the underlying list?
1. Maybe you could create specialized methods to add elements to this list? E.g.

```
ListToSend request = new ListToSend();
request.addInt(1);
request.addLong(2L);
request.addString("3");
request.addInts(List.of(4, 5, 6)); // public void addInts(List<Integer> list) {...}
// and so on
```

2. You could use builder to do similar thing and enforce the types

-

```
MixedList list = MixedList.builder()
    .addInts(List.of(1, 2, 3))
    .addLong(1L)
    ... // and so on
new ListToSend(list);
```

where `ListToSend extends DataToSend<MixedList>`

3. Creating some wrapper object per data type inside the list and maybe using `Optional`

-

```
interface MixedType<T> {
    Class<?> getType();
    T getValue();
}
class IntType implements MixedType<Integer> {...}
class FloatType implements MixedType<Float> {...}
class StringType implements MixedType<String> {...}

class ListToSend extends DataToSend<List<MixedType>>
```

But that that requires you to write your own serializer and anybody can then add new type which might be good or bad depending on your use case.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the issue you raise regarding default values of primitives - thanks for this.